# Change PHP parameter symbol from "?" to "/"

Tags: php

I am trying to make a website with a dynamically loading page, but I do not want to have to use `?name=` in my parameters.

By default it would look like `example.com/page?name=example`
But I would like it to look like `example.com/page/example`

I've had a google but I can't find anything helpful. All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is called "request rewriting". There are _tons_ of existing answers here on SO and out on the internet that demonstrate how to do that.

Comment: Thank you, Was not sure what it was called. I will have a look

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with php. Request rewriting is performed on the level of the request protocol, so on http level. Rules for that are implemented inside the http server. So an answer also depends on what http server you use as a base for your solution.

Comment: I have now finished it with the code `RewriteRule page/(.+)$ page/index.php?name=$1 [L]`, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.